# racket scheme geiser path not found

Tags: emacs, path, scheme, geiser

I followed the directions in the other questions about this problem but it does not seem to solve mine. So this is a duplicate only because the other answers do not work.

.eamcs scheme part looks like this:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin/racket")
```

This is literally where the binary is on my system.

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_9: /Applications/Racketv6.2/bin/racket: No such file or directory
```

both of these work fine in the terminal:

alias racket='/Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin/racket'
alias raco='/Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin/raco'

when i paste the path from my bash file and the run-geiser I get:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_9: /Applications/Racketv6.2/bin/racket: No such file or directory
```

but it literally exists because I can racket and raco inside the terminal.

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Does "/Applications/Racket v6.2/bin/racket" work too?

Comment: It automagically reformats the string to include some crazy emacs escape character. see my answer below.

Comment: Spaces are normally fine in OS X.

Comment: Yea I have no idea why it was not working. Maybe it's time for system wipe/reinstall. I eventually figured it out though. I hope this is useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the file from Racket v6.2 to Racket solved my issue. OSX does not like spaces apparently.